# Unknown file extension ".csv" in nodejs when using npm node-csv and csvtojson

Tags: node.js, json, csv, npm

I am trying to convert a csv file to a json file using npm node-csv and csvtojson.
I installed both in visual studio code, and wrote the following code as per the example in the csvtojson github page:

```
import csv from 'csvtojson';
csv().fromFile('./csvfile.csv').then((response1) => {
console.log(response1);
});
```

However, I am getting an error message:

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".csv" for PATH.csvfile.csv
```

I am not sure what the issue is. I checked the packages in visual studio code, and they are installed correctly and appear in the packages list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some days ago face the same issue. Here is how I solved it with csv2json, don't forget to import it

.createReadStream(`${__dirname}/data/mydata.csv`) - Here i put directory of data.csv

```js
server.get('/api/v1/graph', async (req, res) => {
  await fs
    .createReadStream(`${__dirname}/data/mydata.csv`)
    .pipe(
      csv2json({
        year: Number, // here is uyour data with Types, according to .csv file
        level_1: String,
        level_2: String,
        value: Number,
      })
    )
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('data.json'))
  res.json({ result: 'ok' })
})
```

Comment: is there a difference between csv2json and csvtojson? They appear to be 2 different packages

Comment: no difference in implementation, but for me when i tried to read documentation csv2json was much clearer